# How to use the AS keyword with unknown type

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am trying to use the AS keyword with an unknown type. Here is my code:

```
public GetData(Type MyType, string CSVPath)
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(MyType);

    try
    {
        _Data = engine.ReadFile(CSVPath) as MyType;  //error here
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

as you can see in this code I am getting an error were MyType is. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: You basically can't use `as` there. When dealing the `Type MyType`, you are now in the land of metadata and reflection. Once you start down *that* dark path, forever will it dominate your destiny.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? `as` should return null and not through an exception.

Comment: @Jetti, the error here would be *compile time*. This won't run, let alone return null.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Makes sense. My first hunch was that it couldn't be used but I wasn't exactly sure why. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generic method instead of passing in a `Type` as a parameter:

```
public void GetData<T>(string CSVPath)
{
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(T));
    _Data = engine.ReadFile(CSVPath) as T;
    if (_Data != null)
    {
        //correct type, do the rest of your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: For that the class needs to be generic (so that _Data is of type T). And if _Data is already of type T, you don't need GetData to be generic.

Comment: Good call, I took the OP's code without really reading into it. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @zmbq: There is more than the `as` in the try block.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking... This indeed looks better, but while we're making things generic, we should make FileHelperEngine generic, so that its ReadFile always returns a T. I hope OP can do all that, it will result in much nicer code.

Comment: One additional caveat is that you need to specify that T is a class, like so: 'public void GetData<T>(string CSVPath) where T : class'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand. First, using `as` doesn't throw an exception, it just returns null.

Second, I'm pretty sure you don't want to cast, you just want to check the type, so you need the `is` operator. But since `MyType` is only known at runtime, you indeed need reflection. It's quite simple:

```
object o = engine.Readfile(CSVPath);
if(MyType.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType())
    _Data = o;
else
    Console.WriteLine("Mismatching types: {0} is not of type {1}", o.GetType(), MyType);
```

Note: I'm assuming `_Data` is of type `object`, otherwise, you just use the `as` operator with `_Data`'s type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that does this, though I have a hard time thinking of a good case for a dynamic cast like this.:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private object _data;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().EntryPoint();
        }

        public void EntryPoint()
        {
            GetData(typeof(string), "Test");
            Console.WriteLine(_data);
        }

        public void GetData(Type myType, string csvPath)
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine(myType, csvPath);

            // This is the line that does it.
            _data = Convert.ChangeType(engine.ReadFile(csvPath), myType);
        }

        private class FileHelperEngine
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public FileHelperEngine(Type t, string value) { Value = value.ToString(); }

            public string ReadFile(string path) { return Value; }
        }
    }
}
```